# Spring Data + Mongo case-insensitieve Text Search

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to implement case insensitive text search over several fields in mongodb using spring data repositories. I have found 2 solutions, each having couple disadvantages:

1. Using regex:

   ```
   @Query("{'status': 'ACTIVE', $or: [{'title': {$regex : ?0, $options: 'i'}}, {'location.text': {$regex : ?0, $options: 'i'}}]}")
   Page<Article> findAllActiveBySearchString(String search, Pageable pageable);
   ```

Such query fails on strings "/", "*", and returns all entries on ".", so I have to escape theese characters or somehow filter it, but I even don't know how many such queries could exist. So my question is **how to 100% ensure that query performs search treating every character as plain not special one**.

2. Using $text index, that requires creation of that index before(not a problem). Solution also has better performance, is not it?

   ```
   @Query("{'status': 'ACTIVE', $text: {$search: ?0}}")
   Page<Article> findAllActiveBySearchString(String search, Pageable pageable);
   ```

I wonder that it's not case insensitive, so I have to create special field with lowercase data and index it - **is that only way to achieve my goal, or I missed something?**

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb is not optimized for full text seach, so you have to cope with the limitation or use another search engine like elasticsearch or solr.

Internally those are doing the same you are doing. Using different analyzers like lowercase, stopword filtering, word stemming or n-gram analyzing for fuzzy search for example.

When you want to stick to MongoDb you have to write and index these features on your own.